# Subtracting each value of a column from a value in a column of another dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 375k rows. I need to subtract values in each row of a column of that dataframe from a value in one row of another data frame. The code I used is:

```
`i=1
 for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
     check <-  df1 %>% mutate(col1 = (df1[i,2] - df2[1,2])^2)
     i+1
  }`
```

However, due to the number of rows, it takes almost 2 hours to get done with the operation and I need to do this with all rows of df2. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do `df1 %>% mutate(col1 = (col2 - first(col2))^2)`

Comment: I need to do this with each column of df1 and all rows of df2

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop, this can be vectorized by subtracting all the columns within `mutate_all` with the `first` element of the 1st column of 'df2'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
         mutate_all(funs((. - first(df2[[1]]))^2))
```

---

Based on the comments, if we need to subtract the corresponding columns of 'df1 with that of `first` element in 'df2' columns, then `Map` can be used

```
data.frame(Map(`-`, df1, df2[1,]))
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
map2_df(df1, df2[1,], `-`)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 5*10, replace = TRUE), ncol=5))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 5*10, replace = TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it throws the following error:                              Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Unsupported vector type language

Comment: @RahulSreenivasan  Based on the example I showed, it is not throwing any error.  Do you have `numeric` columns?

Comment: Also, is there any way i could repeat the same operation for all columns of df2 as well? df1 and df2 have same column names, so i need to subtract all values of one column in df1 from every value of the column with the same name in df2. This has to be done for all coulmns. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, all columns in my dataframes are numeric

Comment: @RahulSreenivasan  It depends on whether both datasets have the same number of columns.  If it is the case, then `data.frame(Map('-', df1, df2[1,]))`

Answer (score 0):

With R you want to 'vectorise your operations'. That is you want to operate on the entire vector (column in this instance) at once essentially, as opposed to working through each row individually, as a for loop does.

So, if my df2 is `df1 <- data.frame(mycol = c(1,2,3,4))` and my df2 is `df2 <- data.frame(mycol2 = c(2,3,4,5))`. Then you could write something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(mycol = c(1,2,3,4))

df2 <- data.frame(mycol2 = c(2,3,4,5))

df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(mynewcol = mycol - df2[1,1]^2)
```

`df2[1,1]` is essentially creating a new object, so if you wanted an intermediate step you could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(mycol = c(1,2,3,4))

df2 <- data.frame(mycol2 = c(2,3,4,5))

my_new_object <- as.integer(df2[1,1])

df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(mynewcol = mycol - my_new_object^2)
```